# Why does Samba list the whole server folder-structure

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing

I'm rather new to Linux and Samba and tried to create a share to store some files on my server.

This is what I did:

- Installed samba
- Created Unix user
- Created Samba user
- Created the folder I want to be accessible
- Set the user and group of the new folder to the newly created user/group
- Opened the /etc/samba/smb.conf and created a share like so:

Share:

```
[myshare]
  comment = Files for the server
  path = /var/samba_node
  valid users = myuser
  read only = no
  guest ok = no
  browseable = yes
  writeable = yes
```

I'm using Filezilla to connect to my server and everything works fine. I see the folder and have permissions to create and read files.

But why is it, that I can also see the file structure of the whole server? I only want to be able to see the shared folder but I can see everything. I have no permission to do anything but I can see every file and folder on the whole server.

[image: All Folders are visible]

As you can see, all folders and subfolders in / can be seen, even though my share should only include /var/samba_node.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Because you are using an FTP / SFTP client. Presumably you also set up an FTP / SFTP server on the Linux box. Samba / SMB has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was totally unaware that Samba is not a FTP-Server

Comment: But with a correctly setup FTP-Server (like vsftpd) I should be able to achieve to only make one certail Folder visible, right? @Morbius1